# How do I deal with "undefined reference to dlopen" errors while compiling and using OpenFST on Ubuntu?

Tags: dynamic-linking

Trying to compile and use [OpenFST](http://www.openfst.org/) on Ubuntu 13.10 leads to link errors like "undefined references to dlopen". How does one fix this? Searching online suggests including `-ldl` in the gcc command line, but that is not sufficient.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Compile as follows:

```
./configure LDFLAGS=-Wl,--no-as-needed
make
sudo make install
```

To compile your `a.cpp` which uses the library, do

```
g++ -I /usr/local/include a.cpp /usr/local/lib/libfst.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -ldl
```

It is important the `-ldl` appears after `-Wl,--no-as-needed`.

Running your program works as you'd expect from the README provided by OpenFST, you just need to have `/usr/local/lib` in your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. For example,

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib" ./a.out
```

Answer (score 4):

As can be seen in the [Catalogue of Built-In Rules](//gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules):

> Linking a single object file
>
> `n` is made automatically from `n.o` by running the linker (usually called
>   `ld`) via the C compiler. The precise recipe used is:
>
> ```
> $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
> ```

and [Variables Used by Implicit Rules](//gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Variables):

> LDFLAGS
>
> Extra flags to give to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker,
>   `ld`, such as `-L`. Libraries (`-lfoo`) should be added to the LDLIBS variable
>   instead.

So in this case `-ldl` should be set or added to LDLIBS, not LDFLAGS.